# How can you store a specific line from a file in an array in Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am interested if there is a easy way to store a specific line from a file into an array in Groovy (i need it for GroovyAxis in Jenkins). The file would look like this:

```
var1="value1 value2 etc"

var2="a b etc"

var3="test1 test2 test3 etc"
```

I would need test1 test2 test3 etc from var3 to be stored in an array. Right now i use this:

```
def words = []
new File( '/home/workstation/jenkins/params' ).eachLine { line ->
    words << line
}
```

But it stores each line i have into an array, so i have to heavily workaround the config file to get the job done.

Thank you very much

Comment: `if (line.startsWith('var3='))`? What have you tried? What's the concrete problem?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I have no knowledge in Groovy (but it's the only way i can do what i have to do in Jenkins). The above code i have found on another question posted here. I tried searching for ways to modify it to do what i want it to do, but with no succes. The concrete problem is that i haven't found a way to store just test1 test2 test3 etc without var3= or ", just the values between " .

Comment: Groovy runs on the JVM, and uses Java Strings. Read the javadoc of String. It has methods like startsWith, substring, split, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close!

```
def words = [:]
new File( '/home/workstation/jenkins/params' ).eachLine { line ->
    (var, value) = line.split('=')
    words << [(var): value.split(' ')]
}
```

The result is a map of arrays. The key is the variable name and the value is an array.

## update

Oh, it's a property file...

```
Properties properties = new Properties() 
File propertiesFile = new.    File('/home/workstation/jenkins/params') 
propertiesFile.withInputStream { properties.load(it) } 
def result = properties.var3.split(' ').collect { item.minus('"') }
return result
```

Comment: I did forget to filter out the double quotes. Of the top of my head, i just don't remember how  to do it.

Comment: Thank you, with a bit of changes, it works fine. I did it in an ugly way like this (i have no knowledge of Groovy): `def result = []
Properties properties = new Properties()
File propertiesFile = new File('/home/workstation/jenkins/params')
propertiesFile.withInputStream {
    properties.load(it)
}

buffer = properties.var3
buffer2 = buffer.split(' ').toList()

for (item in buffer2){
    result = result + item.minus('"')

}`
return result

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigSlurper` can be useful to load properties/configurations :

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper(new File("my.conf").toURL())
assert config.var2 == "a b etc"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
//cat /tmp/words.txt
//It's must be file Format
//SOME_DETAILS:1234-A0;1456-B1;2456-B0;3436-D0;4467-C0

stage("test"){

    def testArray=[]
    new File('/tmp/words.txt').splitEachLine("[:;]"){line->
        if(line[0]=='SOME_DETAILS')testArray=line[1..-1]
    }
    println testArray
}
```

[image]

After Run it's Output you get 
[image]